# Breeze's MergeStrategy.PreserveChanges does not remove relatedEntities, even though the backend sets them to "null"

Tags: breeze

I am using Breeze with a custom JSON/REST API. When fetching an entity that is already attached to the manager with a MergeStrategy of "PreserveChanges" (and assuming the cached entity's EntityState is "Unchanged"), any dataProperties not explicitly provided by the server are set to null. But navigationProperties are not removed when merging the node with the targetEntity, even if the backend explicitly provides a value of "null" for them. What kind of data should the server send to have Breeze remove the navigationProperty from its entity during merge?

Comment: I think the merge process is the same regardless of the merge strategy -- that the strategy only determines whether a merge will occur or not.  If so, this issue is not specific to PreserveChanges ... would happen for OverwriteChanges too.  Also, what do you mean by "navigationProperties are not removed"?  Removed sounds like removing it from the cache -- which I would not expect to happen.  Do you mean navigationProperties are not set to null?  I would expect the merge process to null the nav prop if the server returns/indicates null for that prop.